# firefox won't start after accidental power fail of ubuntu VM

Tags: 16.04, firefox, crash

I had a fully working ubuntu 16.04 VM (Oracle VM VirualBox) and had an accidental power fail after which firefox refuses to start.

```
dad@Ubuntu-VM-Pluto:~$ firefox

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 2967
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

(crashreporter:2968): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'com.canonical.unity-gtk-module' is not installed

Bus error (core dumped)
```

So I try forced re installation of the offending packages...

```
dad@Ubuntu-VM-Pluto:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk* libunity-gtk* firefox
[sudo] password for dad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcanberra-gtk-dev' for glob 'libcanberra-gtk*'
Note, selecting 'libcanberra-gtk3-dev' for glob 'libcanberra-gtk*'
...
```

But the problem persists.

Is there any way to check the integrity of everything that is installed?

After removing .mozilla and reinstalling firefox as recommended I get this slightly changed behaviour: -

```
dad@Ubuntu-VM-Pluto:~$ firefox
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 6048
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(crashreporter:6061): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'com.canonical.unity-gtk-module' is not installed

[Child 6045, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset     by peer: file /build/firefox-bfYN6l/firefox-            57.0.1+build2/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 353
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: What was the system doing at the moment it lost power? Was it by chance in the midst of an update/upgrade? Have you run an fsck on your Ubuntu filesystem while booted from another media? Do you have data backups?

Comment: save `.mozilla`(the profile) folder inside your home folder and do a reinstall

Comment: Mozilla was open when power went off, there is little of value on the VM, it has is only used for get_iplayer.  There was no update/upgrade going on.  It is a VM so booting from another media is a little tricky...

Comment: Forcing fsck on boot (sudo touch /forcefsck) showed no errors and the problem remains.  When the VM was started immediately after the power failure ubuntu automatically did an fsck and fixed some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same fate albeit on a Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS box. Here is how i solved my problem,,..

1. You will need to first back-up the folder 'bookmarkbackups found on
   this directory ->
   '`/home/*your_directory_name*/.mozilla/firefox/bookmarkbackups`'.
2. Secondly you will need uninstall firefox by writing this command on
   the shell `sudo apt remove firefox` and then re-install using `sudo
   apt-get install firefox`
3. Third you will be required to rename '.mozilla' folder found here `/home/*your_directory_name*/.mozilla/`
4. Fourth you will need to open mozilla and it will be working.

However, you will need to restore your bookmarks(if you had stored any). Ubuntu 16.04 usually stores its backups in `.json` format and not `.html`. Instructions to restore bookmarks store as .json can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/970691#answer-477540)